# Midnight Commander - rescan compressed archive

Tags: linux, mc

When I open any archive (for example zip) in midnight commander it open it and as I understand it caches its content. When you open this archive second time MC uses its cache. How to reset this cache? I ask because my archives change but I see the old content. Ctrl+R doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from developers at mailing list:

This is known issue:
https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/62
https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/2454

As workaround, menu Command -> "Active VFS list", select wanted zip VFS and press "Free VFSs now".